# Django - Pass a model instance specified by template tags into view

Tags: python, django

On my HTML page, I have a list of Agent's (Agent is my custom User model).  Beside each agent is a 'Send Invite' button.  To create a `TeamInvitation`, I need to specify which Agent is attached to its `receiver_agent` field (a OneToOneField with Agent).

There are multiple Agents displayed on the HTML page, and they are listed in order with template tags.  I need to input something after `pk` at `receiver_agent = Agent.objects.get(pk = ???)`, but I don't know what to input.

**views.py**

```
class InviteAgentSearchResults(ListView):
    model = Agent
    form_class = AgentSearchForm
    template_name = 'invite_agent_search_results.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        # ... Code to find correct agent

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        invite = TeamInvitation.objects.create(receiver_agent = Agent.objects.get(pk = ???))
        return HttpResponse('Invite successfully sent.')
```

**HTML:**

```
{% for agent in agent_list %}
<div class="agent">
# ... Some code here

        <form method="post">  # The "Send Invite" button
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button class="button1"><span>Send Invite</span></button>
        </form>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

EDIT: For clarification - The sender is only sending an invitation to **one agent**.  There is a 'Send Invite' button beside each agent.  The invitation, when accepted, will add the Agent into the sender's team.

I need to pass the singular agent specified by 'agent in `{% for agent in agent_list %}` into my views and assign that agent to the `receiver_agent` field.  You'll see that there is a  button for each 'agent' loop; meaning every agent that is displayed on the page has a 'Send Invite' button next to them.  Pressing the button should only send an invite to that particular agent.

Answer (score 0):

This

`receiver_agent = Agent.objects.get(pk = ???)`

Specifies to get a single agent with a specific primary key `pk`

In your case you're looking to get many. You can either use a filter function (if you need to filter by some parameter. Or you can get all agents. Example of both below.

1. Filter by some parameter `agents = Agent.objects.filter(age=25)` this will return a Queryset which you can iterate through in your template.
2. Get all agents `agents = Agent.objects.all()` this also returns a Queryset.

More on this here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-all-objects

Comment: I clarified my question.  I'm only looking to send an invite to a singular agent.  In my HTML, I have a <form> button for every loop in `{% for agent in agent_list %}`.  When the sender presses the 'Send Invite' button, an invitation should be created for the single agent the button is assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter for the agents who are in the team you want to send a team invitation. If you do not have a field which shows in which team the agent is you can not filter it.

Create only one team invitation:

```
TeamInvitation.objects.create(team='someteam')
```

and then the agent filters:

```
agent = Agent.objects.get(pk=somepk)
teaminv = TeamInvitation.objects.filter(team=agent.team)
```

**With that way you can show the agent if he was invited.**

But I do not know why you want to create an **team** invitation for each agent. A team invitation should only be created once and the agent checks if he was invited. Normally you would make an invitation for the hole team and everyone who is in the team gets the invitation. I hope it is clear what I mean.

So you should think about your structure.

Comment: Sorry my question may not have been explained well.  I added some clarification to my question.  I'm only looking to pass a single agent into my view.  The agent is specified by 'agent' in `{% for agent in agent_list %}`.